# Linux Samba share give write access to group

Tags: linux, samba

I have installed on my raspberry pi running debian (raspbian) samba and samba-common-bin

Then I change the config of samba and add the following at the end:

```
[photocam]
comment = Photo taken from camera
path = /tmp/photocam/
valid users = @users
force group = users
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
read only = no
browseable=Yes
writeable=Yes
only guest=no
public=no
```

I have created a user for samba with sudo smbpasswd -a pi

Then when I try to access it I can only read the files, I can't delete or create new ones...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, really stupid from my part, I have realised that the folder I used and created with root so I had to use chown and chgrp commands to put it to the right user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right use chown command to change users to pi this will change all files in the current directory to

```
user=pi, group=pi

sudo chown pi:pi *
```

You may also need to set permissions on the files with chmod command. The following command will change all files in the current directory to

```
775 = rwxrwxr.x

sudo chmod 775 *
```